# Combobox binding in silverlight Ria Services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, combobox, wcf-ria-services

I want to bind a combox with my entity model via domain services.

My entity model: 
COUNTRIES (ID, NAME)
TABLE_TEST (PK_FIELD, FIELD2, COUNTRY_ID)

I created my entity model and the domain service.

My Xaml:

```
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:COUNTRIES, CreateList=true}" Height="0" Name="COUNTRIESDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetCOUNTRIESQuery" Width="0">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:DomainService1 />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:TABLE_TEST, CreateList=true}" Height="0" Name="TABLE_TESTDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetTABLE_TESTQuery" Width="0">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:DomainService1 />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <ComboBox Name="COUNTRIESComboBox"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=COUNTRIESDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ID"
              SelectedValuePath="NAME"
      SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=TABLE_TESTDomainDataSource, Path=COUNTRY_ID}">
    </ComboBox>
```

The combobox is loaded with the correct values (all countries) but looks like it's not bounded with TABLE_TEST. When I change the register of TABLE_TEST, the value of the combo does not change.

What I am doing wrong? I looked many examples but no one is the same escenario, with domain data source and entity model.

I'm working with silverlight 5

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DomainDataSource is an extremely bad fit as a datasource for Silverlight ComboBoxes. So far I've found [Kyle McClennan's [MSFT] ComboBoxDataSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx) the most reliable in the use case you've described. In fact, he advised:

> 1) Do not use the DomainDataSource to populate ComboBoxes
>
> You might
>   think this is drastic or an over reaction, but I stick by the
>   recommendation. Despite the simple samples you’ll see in other places,
>   I think you’re better off avoiding the DDS when working with
>   ComboBoxes. The DDS does not scale for more complex ComboBox
>   scenarios.

In particular, you need to mark your combobox as being Async in the *final* attribute.

```
<ComboBox Name="COUNTRIESComboBox"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=COUNTRIESDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ID"
          SelectedValuePath="NAME"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=TABLE_TESTDomainDataSource, Path=COUNTRY_ID}"
          ex:ComboBox.Mode="Async">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: This example does not apply to me. Ok, he is describing the same situation but he is using a personalized combobox which I don't want. I can't belive that silverlight has no solution to this issue without implementing my own combobox extension...

Comment: It is a standard combobox. The main reason you have issues is because DomainDataSource is asynchronous, and might finish loading the ItemsSource after the SelectedValue has been set. The end result is you losing your SelectedValue. If you don't want to use the extensions, make sure the itemssource is loaded first, then set the selectedvalue. This is what the extension does.

Comment: By the way, I totally agree with your sentiment. Silverlight is too low level and needs years of polish or a third party toolkit to make it useful for rapid LOB development.

Comment: Do you know how to set de SelectedValue property from a DomainDataSource object?

Comment: If you insist on using DomainDataSource, then you have to make sure the COUNTRIESDomainDataSource for has loaded before loading the TABLE_TESTDomainDataSource DDS. Set AutoLoad to false, and then listen for events. It is a lot of work, about half a page each time, and very hard to follow.

Comment: 'It is a lot of work... and very hard to follow'. Ok, maybe is not the best choise but you've been dramatic. Anyway, I think I'm gonna use the extension. Thank you